# Error on function SetArcCostEvaluatorOfAllVehicles();

Tags: c#, .net, routes, error-handling, constraints

When I try to set the cost by the function below:

```
routing.SetArcCostEvaluatorOfAllVehicles((i, j) =>
        {
            return (int)distanciaMatriz[manager.IndexToNode(i), manager.IndexToNode(j)];
        });
```

It returns the following error:

`Error CS1660 Unable to convert lambda expression to type "int" because it is not a delegate type.`

How can I solve this problem? I've already tried to directly cast the return for int, but nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to assign them to int variables to make sure they match the expected delegate signature

```
int nodeI = manager.IndexToNode(i);
int nodeJ = manager.IndexToNode(j);
return (int)distanciaMatriz[nodeI, nodeJ];
```